# Magento core/html_select: Set option class

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, template, html

Magento offers a function to generate a select from the backend: https://magently.com/blog/dropdown-selects-in-magento/

```
$select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock( 'core/html_select' )
    ->setName( 'addresses' )
    ->setOptions( $options );
```

This will give me something like this:

```
<select name="addresses">
    <option value="address1">address1</option>
    <option value="address2">address2</option>
</select>
```

but I want to set a class for the options:

```
<select name="addresses">
    <option value="address1" class="a">address1</option>
    <option value="address2" class="b">address2</option>
</select>
```

My options look like this:

```
$options[] = array(
    'value' => $address->getId(),
    'label' => $address->format( 'oneline' ),
    'parvw' => $address->getParvw()
);
```

`parvw` is the class parameter for the option

How can I set the class options?

Comment: Not sure how to do that with that function. I can think of a few workarounds that may be of use tho: If the purpose is to style them you can use css like:option[value=_address1]  or jquery $('option > select > option[value="address1"]'). Or just a for each loop like: <?php
$select = '<select name="addresses">';
foreach ($options as $option) {
  $select .= '<option value="' . $option['value'] . '" class="' . $option['parvw'] . '">' . $option['value'] . '</option>';
}
$select .= '</select>';
?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento allow us to add additional params to the options of a select.

Here is how you need to modify your options:

```
$options[] = array(
    'value' => $address->getId(),
    'label' => $address->format( 'oneline' ),
    'params' => array ('class' => 'yourclass1')
);

$options[] = array(
    'value' => $address->getId(),
    'label' => $address->format( 'oneline' ),
    'params' => array ('class' => 'yourclass2')
);
```

For more details you can check the functions

- Mage_Core_Block_Html_Select::setOptions()
- Mage_Core_Block_Html_Select::_toHtml()
- Mage_Core_Block_Html_Select::_optionToHtml()